# Can I upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, server, xampp, windows-server-2008

I am creating a web application and want to put it on a server.

I have a server machine that run Windows 2008 R2 Server with a SQL Server 2008 database all set up and ready to use.

Can I put my application on that system or should I upgrade it to Windows 2012 or 2019 server, while also upgrading SQL Server with it?

Note: I was using XAMPP for testing, will SQL Server 2008 be as easy as connecting to PHPmyadmin database in XAMPP?

Comment: It's not in the documentation anymore (that I can see), but it was *technically possible* to upgrade a 2008 instance to 2019, but there is actually no supported way to do it; 2008 isn't supported on a version of Windows that 2019 is. 2019 requires much more recent versions of Windows, and as SQL Server 2008 is so old, it wasn't supported on those versions of Windows. As such, you would be better off doing a [migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#migrate-to-).

Comment: *"will SQL 2008 be as easy as connecting to PHPmyadmin database"* This doesn't make sense; PHPMyAdmin isn't a database engine, it's a web-based interface for interacting with MySQL.

Comment: If you have just a single server and can't perform a proper migration to newer hardware, upgrade the operating system first, then SQL Server immediately after. Or consider upgrading the operating system, installing a _new_ instance of a newer version of SQL Server, and migrating your data to the new instance.

Comment: Upgrade your 2008 database to 2016 first. I would recommend a new operating system and SQL Server instance, rather than updating the existing one

Comment: @Charlieface Disagree. Even SQL Server 2016 didn't support Windows Server 2008 R2, so install / upgrade would probably be blocked, and why go to 2016 anyway when you can be fully supported on something newer. Upgrading the OS first won't remove SQL Server so "support" is less of an issue and only temporary until you can also upgrade SQL Server. I do agree that I'd rather have a brand new machine and migrate, but not sure it's in the cards for the OP.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Maybe 2008 to 2014 to 2019 then? Either way, I think it's not supported to go straight from 2008 to 2019 either with upgrade or with backup/restore

Comment: @AaronBertrand Apparently backup/restore *is* supported, but upgrade is not https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#migrate-to- Obviously didn't meant upgrade the database first, that makes no sense, just meant to use a stepping stone

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, you might have to use an interim version as a stepping stone, though an upgrade might still work even if it's not supported. I was more disagreeing about upgrading the database first, before the operating system, because those checks halt setup immediately. Might not have been what you meant explicitly, but it's how I read it, especially in the context immediately following my comment.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2019 is not supported on Windows Server 2008 R2, which is in any case heavily out-of-date and insecure.

If you wanted to go with a direct upgrade path for your existing server, you must:

- First upgrade the operating system to Windows Server 2012 R2. You must first upgrade to 2012 R2, as [upgrading directly to 2019 or 2022 is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/extended-security-updates-overview#migrate-or-upgrade-on-premises).
- Then upgrade SQL Server to 2014, as upgrading directly to 2019 [is not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/supported-version-and-edition-upgrades-2019?view=sql-server-ver16#migrate-to-).
- Then upgrade the operating system to 2019 or 2022.
- Then upgrade SQL Server to 2019.

---

**Do not do any of the above.** As you can see, it's complex, with multiple points of failure.

Just start with a new Windows Server 2022 image, and install SQL Server 2019.

Then do a backup/restore of all your user databases from your SQL Server 2008 R2 to the new machine. Consider updating the compatibilty level, as well as other database-scoped settings.

Comment: Is there any way to check whether updating the compatibility level will break something or not

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/upgrade-dbcompat-using-qta?view=sql-server-ver16 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-ver16